# How to INSERT an entry without content into a table in ZF2?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2, sql-insert, zend-db

In my database there is a table, that contains only one row: `id`. It's something like a facade for another table:

[image]

Now I want to add an entry into `whatever_set`, in order to be able to create entries in the dependent tables. In `SQL` I would write:

```
INSERT INTO whatever_set VALUES ();
```

But when I try it with `Zend\Db`

```
$action = new Insert(whatever_set');
$data = [];
$action->values($data);
$sql = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);
$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($action);
$result = $statement->execute();
```

I get an [exception](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/blob/master/src/Sql/Insert.php#L174):

> values or select should be present

There are some possible workarounds (see below). But is there though a "Zend way" to save empty with no `VALUES`? How to do this?

---

**Workaround 1**

Custom `Insert` class.

**Workaround 2**

Raw `SQL` like

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO whatever_set VALUES ();';
$result = $this->dbAdapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->execute($sql);
```

Comment: is `id` set to "auto_increment" in the sql schema?

Comment: Yes: `CREATE TABLE whatever_set (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)`